# Include navigation property of navigation property in EF5/6

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-6

Here is my existing code, which fetches a user and gets his groups.

```
        User user = new FetchUserByUsernameServiceCommand(Username, Context).Execute();

        var groupList = user.JoinedGroups.ToList<Group>();

        return groupList;
```

Each `Group` has a navigation property `Image` which has an `ImageUrl`.

I would like to `Include` the `Image` of each `Group` in the `groupList`, but `Include` is not available on the `Lis<Group> groupList` because it is not attached to a `Context`.

How can I include the `Image` navigation property for each `Group`?

Comment: Can you put the code snippet for your "Group" model ?

Answer (score 0):

You can **either** extend your command class and constructor to accept expressions for the navigation properties to include:

```
private string _userName;
private MyContext _context;
private Expression<Func<User, object>>[] _includes;

public FetchUserByUsernameServiceCommand(string userName,
    MyContext context, params Expression<Func<User, object>>[] includes)
{
    _userName = userName;
    _context = context;
    _includes = includes;
}

public User Execute()
{
    IQueryable<User> query = _context.Users;
    if (_includes != null)
    {
        foreach (var include in _includes)
            query = query.Include(include);
    }
    return query.SingleOrDefault(u => u.UserName);
}
```

You would call this like so:

```
User user = new FetchUserByUsernameServiceCommand(
    Username, Context, u => u.JoinedGroups.Select(g => g.Image))
    .Execute();

var groupList = user.JoinedGroups.ToList();
return groupList;
```

**Or** you can use explicit loading:

```
User user = new FetchUserByUsernameServiceCommand(
    Username, Context)
    .Execute();

var groupList = Context.Entry(user).Collection(u => u.JoinedGroups).Query()
    .Include(g => g.Image)
    .ToList();

return groupList;
```

Note that only the first option is eager loading in the sense that user plus groups plus images are loaded together in a single database request. The second option (explicit loading) will run two database queries - the first one that only loads the `User` object in the command executor and the second one that loads groups plus images for that user.